# ATI Multiple Monitors and Clone Mode?

Tags: amd-radeon, external-display, display-settings

I own the Radeon HD 5870 and i want to use 2 Monitors with the same resolution in clone mode:

- my main display
- my TV

.. while *also* extending to a monitor with a different resolution (so eyefinity is not an option).

The only tools I found are used for gaming, but I want to use it for Browsing and Multimedia.

I know that the HDMI port uses the same stream as one of the DVI ports, so is it possible to clone the connection to both ports while extending the second DVI port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to split either a DVI or an HDMI and then extend using another port.  There are only two "internal clocks" on the AMD cards, so only two DVI/DVI/HDMI ports can be active at one time. Cloning still requires a "clock".